# Selenium/PHPUnit. Is it possible to open a clean a new window/browser on top of the window/browser?

Tags: selenium, phpunit

I have a window thats logged in to a website. For example, I logged into my e-mail on hotmail. Is it possible to open a clean window/browser on top of that and log into another e-mail, use that window/browser to test, then close or switch browsers and do more testing?

Answer (score 1):

For opening a new window you can try this

```
selenium.openWindow("Url To Open","MyWindow");
selenium.selectWindow("MyWindow");

//Do your operations here

selenium.selectWindow(null);//This will take you to default Window
```

Hope this would help you.